# How to create a simple bot that auto-reacts to messages containing a certain trigger sentence?

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm setting up a Discord server for me and my friends, and I'm in need of a bot able to add 20 reactions to any message in which a certain trigger phrase was typed.
I used to have a bot that could do that, but it has been updated and limited to 3 reactions, which isn't working for me.

So here I am, with my very basic understanding of programming, trying to setup a very basic bot for that sole purpose.

I already tried a simple bot proposition found on YT, but it didn't work at all, and I'm at a loss to know why and how to fix it.

So this was the proposition I tried and didn't manage to make functional:

```
import discord
from discord.ext    import commands
from discord.ext.commands   import Bot
import asyncio

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print ("Ready to react, boss !")


@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if(message.channel.id == "550373218758688790"):
        await bot.add_reaction(message, ":war_tank:552569109108490252")


bot.run("NTY5OTQ0NTMyMzIyNjE1MzI2.XL4IBg.WH-Ms1DWKJN8qGBBLAxdGye0q2I")
```

So this one was supposed to react to every message with a reaction, and I was planning on working from there, but it didn't even work.
Instead, I got a message in the cmd log for each message and that looked like this:

```
Ignoring exception in on_message
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "G:\Jeux\Discord Bot\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 255, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "G:\Bureau\TotemReact Bot\bot.py", line 16, in on_message
    await bot.add_reaction(message, ":war_tank:552569109108490252")
AttributeError: 'Bot' object has no attribute 'add_reaction'
```

So if anyone with actual skills (considering mine, I will be easily impressed) can point me in the right direction, I will be more than happy.

Thank you for your time and attention.

Comment: You need to recreate your token for the bot now! Anyone can use the current one in your question to take control of your bot and use it for malicious purposes. Editing it out isn't enough because anyone has access to the edit history.

Answer (score 2):

You're looking at old tutorials.  `Client.add_reaction` was moved to [`Message.add_reaction`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Message.add_reaction) in discord.py 1.0

The functionality you describe could look something like:

```
default_emojis = [
    "\N{GRINNING FACE}",
    "\N{KEYCAP DIGIT ONE}"
]

custom_emojis = [
    "war_tank"
]

async def react(message):
    for emoji in default_emojis:
        await message.add_reaction(emoji)
    for emoji in message.guild.emojis:
        if emoji.name in custom_emojis:
            await message.add_reaction(emoji)

@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == bot.user:
        return
    if "react to me" in message.content.lower():
        await react(message)
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it's working quite well.

I'm now trying to make it so that only people with a certain level of role can trigger the reaction, but I'm still ripping my eyes out in frustration.

I know it's a bit much of me to ask for so much information for a little thing like that, but that would be really appreciated.

Thank you anyway for that first bit !

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you're going to want to change your token now, if you haven't already.

You're using syntax from a version of discord.py, v0.16, that isn't supported anymore.
See [the guide for migrating to v1](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/migrating.html), specifically the [Models are Stateful section](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/migrating.html#models-are-stateful).
You should use [`Message.add_reaction`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Message.add_reaction) rather than `Bot.add_reaction`.

Answer (score 0):

first register on the replit site

secondly create new repyl and create node.js

and create new file and rename server.js

and copy these codes

for server.js

```
const express = require('express');

const server = express();



server.all('/', (req, res)=>{

   res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html');

   res.write('<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto Condensed" rel="stylesheet"> <style> body {font-family: "Roboto Condensed";font-size: 22px;} <p>Hosting Active</p>');

   res.end();

})



function keepAlive(){

   server.listen(3000, ()=>{console.log("Server is online!")});

}



module.exports = keepAlive;
```

for index.js

```
    const Discord = require('discord.js');
    const client = new Discord.Client();
    
    const mySecret = process.env['mysecrettoken']
    
    const keepAlive = require("./server");
    
    
    client.on('message', msg => {
    
    if (msg.attachments.size > 0) { //Make sure there are attachments at all
        var react = false; //Do we react to the message? Default to false
    
        msg.attachments.forEach(attachment => { //Check each attachment to see if it's a jpg, png, or jpeg
            if (attachment.url.includes(".jpg") || attachment.url.includes(".png") || attachment.url.includes(".jpeg")) {
                react = true; //It's an image! We want to react to the message
            };
        });
    
        if (react === true) { //React to the message
            msg.react('837608362719969291');
            msg.react('837608381283827734');
            msg.react('837608396659097640');
            msg.react('837608412337668096');
            msg.react('837608426821124096');
        };
    };
    
    }
    )
    
    keepAlive();


client.login(process.env.mysecrettoken);
```

create your first discord bot and give it admin rights. You can watch youtube videos about it how create dc bot and give it to admin rights.

click this site  https://discord.com/developers/applications/

[create your dc bot give admin rights regenerate and copy your toke paste to replit secret values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vrpzE.png)

[copy url add monitoring sites and your discord bot is ready to use 7/24 using](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gdhuj.png)

copy your token and create your mysecrettoken

monitoring sites example : https://uptimerobot.com

your dc bot is ready